# Get dynamic dates for URL on any day of the month

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-requests

I'm scraping a website with requests.  The URL requires dynamic dates so i'm generating the dates to use with the following variables:

```
stmDt = (pd.to_datetime('today').date()+ pd.offsets.MonthBegin(-1)).strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
todDt = (pd.to_datetime('today').date()).strftime('%d-%b-%Y') 
snmDt = (pd.to_datetime('today').date()+ pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)).strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
enmDt = (pd.to_datetime('today').date()+ pd.offsets.MonthEnd(2)).strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
```

For this example, i'm running this script on 11/30/2022 (last day of the month).

- stmDt = start this month date (first day of month on which we run script - 11/1/2022)
- todDt = today (11/30/2022)
- snmDt = start next month (12/1/2022)
- enmDt = end next month (12/31/2022)

The date variables are correct most of the time, but it appears (for november run dates):

- On the first day of the month: stmDt shows the first day of the
  previous month (10/1/22)
- On the last day of the month: enmDt shows the last day two months
  from now (1/31/23)

How can I tweak these so they always give me the correct dates?  Happy to use other packages to accomplish etc

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using  [dateutil.relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

today = datetime.now()

stmDt = today.replace(day=1).strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
todDt = today.strftime('%d-%b-%Y') 
snmDt = (today + relativedelta(months=1)).replace(day=1).strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
enmDt = ((today + relativedelta(months=2)).replace(day=1) - relativedelta(days=1)).strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
```